# Make linear layout selectable like a list item in a list view (Android)

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-linearlayout

I know how to add an onClick listener to a LinearLayout to make the whole layout a click target, but I'd like to have the LinearLayout get highlighted when tapped just like a list item in a list view. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 27):

I prefer a simpler way:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/layoutIdentifier"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- put views here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

You can't change the state-pressed background this way, but sometimes you don't really need to.

Comment: @AhmadRezaEnshaee Of course it does.. as you can see 10 years later.

Comment: Pardon. I didn't understand the OP's question correctly when I was reading it. I'll remove the comment.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this and this is what I came up with.  In your layout, set the background to a drawable resource:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/clickable_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/clickable"> 
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in drawable, add clickable.xml as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />      
</selector>
```

Then it's up to you whether or not you want to add a click handler in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all the elements inside the layout clickable=false. Then you should mimic selection behavior by setting layout background to some color and set all the other ones with background transparent when a layout is clicked. You can use layout id as index to know which layout is selected.