# Is there a more "Android" way to have my items in a grid view hold a "Selected" state?

Tags: android, gridview

I have built a `GridView` populated by an `Adapter` of `RelativeLayouts` that contains a top level `ImageView`. The `ImageView` is not displayed until the user taps the item, thereby creating a "*selected*" effect for the individual `View`. When the user taps a different item, I hide the selected item on the previously selected `View`.

This works fine, but I'm curious if there's a more native Android way to handle this situation. I'm not seeing any sort of `setSelected()` (ish) method but perhaps I'm overlooking something?

Comment: Maybe you want this kind of behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821044/make-linear-layout-selectable-like-a-list-item-in-a-list-view-android

Answer (score 2):

Any subclass of `View` should have a `setSelected()` method, which includes `RelativeLayout`. You should keep track of the selected position in your adapter, and then in your `getView()` method:

```
myRelativeLayout.setSelected(selectedPosition == position);
```

Which will work if you're using a selector that handles `state_selected`. For your method, you could just say:

```
myImageView.setVisibility(selectedPos == pos ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
```

And when you register a click (in your `OnItemSelectedListener` or `OnItemClickListener`, or whatever you're using) just call your adapter's `setSelectedPosition()` method with the touched position, and then call your adapter's `notifyDatasetChanged()` method.